# c# firebase Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException

Tags: c#, firebase, winforms

This error appear in the second line:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: \<. Path '', line 0, position 0.'
```

```
FirebaseResponse response = client.Get("users/" + txtUser.Text);

Utilizador resUser = response.ResultAs\<Utilizador\>(); (error on this line)
```

This is for a login with the data stored in realtime database on firebase

I'm expecting that this code made a login

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the first character the parse has encountered is a `<`, which indicates that the response is coming back as either HTML or XML/SOAP.
I'd suggest to see if you can look at the response to determine the type and see what can be done from there.

As a possible suggestion:

- If it is HTML, it may be redirecting to a login prompt.
- If it is XML or SOAP, you may need to request the response type to `application/json`

Comment: I don't know how to fix it

Comment: @Azevedo Given the information you have given me, I don't know either.
Try putting a breakpoint on and reading the raw response from the call to `client.Get(...)`.

My best guess is that you haven't authenticated properly, and you are being returned a login prompt, but that is a guess.